# Random Forests classifier Over/Underfitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

In a given dataset I trained a Random Forest classifier using sklearn package in Python. I used the `class_weight=balanced` parameter in order to balance the imbalanced classes, i.e their ratio is approximately 70-30.

For a training dataset with 10 features per entry and with 3,2 million entries I got this classification report:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

  0               0.92      0.94      0.93    510310
  1               0.74      0.64      0.69    124374

avg / total       0.88      0.88      0.88    634684
```

In an effort to enhance my classifier (and achieve better accuracy for class 1 which has fewer samples) I balanced the training dataset myself, using pandas random sampling function `pd.sample(frac=0.3)` which for all the I know shuffles the data before the sampling, I got the classification report below:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

  0               0.89      0.85      0.87      153117
  1               0.86      0.90      0.88      161326
avg / total       0.87      0.87      0.87      314443
```

My training dataset at this point has 10 features per entry with approximately 1,6 million entries.

An issue rises when I tried it in a test dataset (test dataset consisting of 4 million entries). Then my model's performance dropped significantly as you can see:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

  0               0.56      0.24      0.33   1221872
  1               0.06      0.20      0.09    277578

avg / total       0.47      0.23      0.29   1499450
```

At this point I must add that I know that my dataset's profile is consistent. I mentioned that as inconsistencies between train and test data could have such a negative effect in my model's accuracy.

Moreover I tried fitting a Voting Classifier that consisted of linear, gaussian and tree estimators and again k-fold CV returned amazing results (~90% precision and recall) but when I tested it in an unseen dataset or even a shuffle instance of my dataset I got extremely poor results.

I have some experience with ML classifiers, but I have never encountered anything like this.

The only parameter I have fiddled with is the number of trees in the forest which is why I cannot believe that I overfit my classifier as I get similar results when I use e.g. 60 and 200 trees.

Are RF affected from imbalanced datasets?

Shouldn't I get at least decent results when I balance my classes?

Are RF biased from the training dataset, i.e. given a 50% - 50% distribution in the training dataset does it expect a similar distribution to the test dataset and it cannot perform as expected given a 70-30 test set?

Sorry for the long post. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
X = load_data()
labels = X['label'].values
X.drop(['label'], axis=1, inplace=True)

final_X = X.values
#scaling makes not difference for RF but left it here since I tried
# a Voting Classifier as well afterwards
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scl = scaler.fit_transform(final_X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scl, labels,     
test_size=0.2, random_state=46)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print ("Classifier:", clf)
print("Detailed classification report:")
print()
print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
print()
y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: Are you generating your initial classification reports by predicting on your upsampled training data?

Comment: Not sure what you meant but all my reports are generated using a 80-20 split using sklearn's train_test_split. So to my knowledge there are no overlaps between test and train data. The weird thing for me is that 5-fold CV returns great results that do not explain why its performance drops that much afterwards.

Comment: Post your code that upsamples and fits the model

Comment: I added the part where I get the data, fit the model and get the classification report.